# Resteasy compatibility with Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, maven, resteasy

I'm trying to create a Maven project with the Restfull Web Services that make use of RESTEasy and Hibernate.
This is my POM.xml file:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>org.jboss.resteasy</id>
        <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Dipendenze resteasy -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1.Final</version>  
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxb-provider</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1.Final</version>  
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jettison-provider</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1.Final</version>  
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-hibernatevalidator-provider</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Dipendenze Mysql -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.30</version>  
    </dependency>

     <!-- Dipendenze Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.Final</version>  
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.Final</version>  
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>7.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

My server error is

```
Grave: 830 [admin-listener(5)] INFO org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ConfigurationBootstrap - Adding scanned @Provider: org.jboss.resteasy.api.validation.ResteasyViolationExceptionMapper Grave: 1354 [http-listener-1(4)] ERROR org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler - failed to execute Grave: javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: Could not find resource for full path: localhost:8080/EffecTWeb
```

When I run the project I get a blank screen on the browser page, and I think this is due to a compatibility problem between the libraries. 
Can anyone tell me which versions of resteasy/hibernate libraries are compatible? Need I to add additional libraries?

Comment: Anything on the server logs?

Comment: Grave:   830 [admin-listener(5)] INFO org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ConfigurationBootstrap - Adding scanned @Provider: org.jboss.resteasy.api.validation.ResteasyViolationExceptionMapper

Grave:   1354 [http-listener-1(4)] ERROR org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler - failed to execute
Grave:   javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: Could not find resource for full path: http://localhost:8080/EffecTWeb/

Comment: add your web.xml in your description